# Specifying response.redirect paths in sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm a asp.net beginner. i'd like to specify a redirect url in sitemap so as to build the nav me.
The url:

```
 response.redirect("my_accordionpage.aspx?pane5)
```

The sitemap:

```
<siteMapNode url="response.redirect("my_accordionpage.aspx?pane5)" title="Heritage"  description="" />
```

Comment: You should only need to specify the path, leaving out the `response.redirect` part. See [aspnet_navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp) for some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments, there is no need for `response.redirect` in the URL. Specifying the path is all that is needed.

```
<siteMapNode url="my_accordionpage.aspx?pane5" title="Heritage" description="" />
```

[This W3 article](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp) goes into a little more detail with some different examples.